# Ball and Stick molecule modelling program for Mac OS

Tags: mac, software-recommendation

Does anyone know any good programs for making ball and stick molecular models on the Mac? I'm looking for something to produce high quality 3D models with nice lighting, like this on

[image]

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pentane-3D-balls.png).

Comment: If I remember correctly, pictures of such molecular models appeared on the side of the box my eMac came in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/wiki/Main_Page). It's open source, and cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

Apple it self recommends [some](http://www.apple.com/science/solutions/chemistry.html) of them. [VIDA](http://www.eyesopen.com/vida) by OpenEye and [MarvinTools](http://www.chemaxon.com/products/marvin/) by ChemAxon provide 3D modeling.